# Proving that stochastic processes are equal using test functions.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, distribution-theory

I am reading section 5.9 on continuous time filtering in [Measure Theory and Filtering](http://services.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/applied-probability-and-stochastic-networks/measure-theory-and-filtering-introduction-and-applications?format=HB).
Here I have come across a technique, which is used in several of the proofs in the book to show that particular stochastic processes are equal (in some sense).

It goes something like this; Let $\psi$ be a test function. According to the book, that is $\psi \in C^2$ and $\psi$ has compact support. It then seem like if $(X_t(x))_{t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}}$ and $(Y_t(x))_{t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}}$ are stochastic processes (or collections of stochastic processes indexed by $x\in \mathbb{R}$) and if
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \psi(x) X_t(x) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \psi(x) Y_t(x) dx
$$
then we can conclude that $X_t(x) = Y_t(x)$ in some sense for every $t \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Does anyone know where I can read about this kind of proof technique using "test functions" in this sense. I am new to [distribution theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions) which as far as I can see also deals with "test functions", but I am not sure if this is the place to go. A reference to a book would be good.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924382/if-f-g-in-l-loc1-omega-and-langle-f-phi-rangle-langle-g-phi-ra?rq=1

Comment: Oh, this question really is about distribution theory? Mostly, when a probability question is tagged 'distribution-theory' the proper tag should be 'probability-distributions'.

Comment: @md2perpe, Whether the answers are to be found in distribution theory or somewhere else, that is exactly my question.

Comment: This is about generalized stochastic processes and the related notion of random Schwartz distributions. You can get a quick intro in the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09326 In fact the tags "distribution-theory" about Schwartz distributions and "probability-distributions" are both appropriate.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you so much. I will take a look at the article.